# Как брать цвет из таблицы XSL?

Tags: xslt, xsl

```
<item>
    <num color="#336600">1</num>
    <val>0</val>
</item>
<item>
    <num color="#330000">2</num>
    <val>1</val>
</item>
<item>
    <num color="#330066">3</num>
    <val>1</val>
</item>
<item>
    <num color="#660033">4</num>
    <val>2</val>
</item>
<item>
    <num color="#006633">5</num>
    <val>3</val>
</item>
<item>
    <num color="#000033">6</num>
    <val>5</val>
</item>
<item>
    <num color="#663300">7</num>
    <val>8</val>
</item>
<item>
    <num color="#003300">8</num>
    <val>13</val>
</item>
<item>
    <num color="#003366">9</num>
    <val>21</val>
</item>
```

Как брать из нее цвет, чтобы его можно было применить?

Просто пока у меня получатеся только так..[image: Результат]

Как реализованно у меня:

```
<xsl:template match="variants/sequence">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@variant = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <table border="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" >
          <tr>
            <th>N</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
              <xsl:value-of select="//num/@color"/>
              <th bgcolor="@color" style="color:white;">
                <xsl:value-of select="num"/>
              </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Значение</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
              <th>
                <xsl:value-of select="val"/>
              </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Покажите свой код.

Comment: Добавил свою реализацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фигурные скобки означают, что это выражение, а не литерал.
Точка в пути означает текущий узел (item).

```
<xsl:for-each select="items/item">                            
  <th bgcolor="{./num/@color}" style="color:white;">
    <xsl:value-of select="num"/>
  </th>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Вариант с промежуточной переменной:

```
<xsl:for-each select="items/item">              
  <xsl:variable name="color" select="./num/@color" />
  <th bgcolor="{$color}" style="color:white;">
    <xsl:value-of select="num"/>
  </th>
</xsl:for-each>
```